# Keep row group header in line with values

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report that looks kinda like a web form, with the label in column one, the value on the same row in column two.  The first few rows display data about the person.  The last row is for multiple detail records.  The problem is I can either have the details header repeat for every record, not what I want, or have the title appear in a row above the details.  I want the label to display even with the first row of details.

Default view, not what I want:

```
Name:   John Smith
Number: 123456
Email:  blah@smith.com

Books:  Green Eggs and Ham
Books:  Sam I Am
Books:  And the Moon Glowed
```

Added a group header, still not quite right:

```
Name:   John Smith
Number: 123456
Email:  blah@smith.com

Books:  
        Green Eggs and Ham
        Sam I Am
        And the Moon Glowed
```

What I want:

```
Name:   John Smith
Number: 123456
Email:  blah@smith.com

Books:  Green Eggs and Ham
        Sam I Am
        And the Moon Glowed
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you generate that report with a sql query? Becasue if you have that i can update it.

Comment: I do. Not sure how that would change things unless you are thinking to put all the books into a single result instead of different rows.

Comment: Please add more specifics, for example add a printscreen. I have no idea in what direction to look for an answer. You make the report in SSRS? How is your dataset set? What is the exact syntax your using? Possibly you need to change the row as an expression. But for now, I don't have a clue what you did.

Comment: where you get the label 'Books' from? Because if you get get it from db like `descriptor`, `value` i can update that.

Comment: If I interpret the printscreen correct, you can move the expression [BookTitle] one row up? And delete CheckoutDate and ReturnDate (?), possibly they take more rowspace than you would expect from what you see on your screen. SSRS has a tendency to mess up your lay out. But still, not sure whether that's your problem.

Comment: Problem is I need to display multiple book names for each person and I want the word "Titles:" to appear right next to the first book, not above it.

Comment: Possibly change the expression so that it is a concatenation of some spaces ('            ') and BookTitle? Not the best solution, but maybe it helps. And then it is on one line?

Comment: I thought about an expression that will conditionally show "Title"?  The textbox would know to hide for records 2 or higher?

Comment: So far this seems to work.  Put the label back in the same row as the value. Set a visibility expression on the text box of =IIf(RowNumber("table1_ReturnDate") > 1, True, False) which hides Title for record 2 or higher.